# How to insert values row by row in a gridview using temporary table(Data Table)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridviews in my asp.net page. Where the datas are coming from two different databases. In that, one gridview has select row function. Now what I want to do is, I need to generate my 3rd gridview row by row according to the selection of the 1st gridview's 2 cells and the 2nd gridview 1st column data.(1st column data is common for all the rows).

The values in the gridview is showing as expected, But it will only hold one row data at a time. When I go ahead to select another value from the dropdownlist the gridview refreshes and the existing data will disappear and the new data appears.

How can I have the selected datas inserted row by row in a gridview?

**Here are my code given below:**

```
protected void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SetInitialRowToGrid();
                int rowIndex = 0;

                if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
                {
                    // Get TempTable from viewstate
                    var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];
                    DataRow tempRow = null;

                    if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i <= tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            // Get Grid's Label values
                            var EmpID =
                                (Label)grdEmp.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblEmpID");
                            var firstName =
                                (Label)grdEmp.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblFirstName");

                            var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();                

                            var planID =
                                (Label)grdPlanID.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblPlanID");

                            // Create new row and update Row Number
                            tempRow = tempTable.NewRow();

                            tempTable.Rows[0]["Emp_ID"] = EmpID.Text;
                            tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["First_Name"] = firstName.Text;
                            tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["Created_Time"] = date;
                            tempTable.Rows[i - 1]["Plan_ID"] = planID.Text;

                            rowIndex++;
                        }

                        // Add data to datatable and viewstate
                        tempTable.Rows.Add(tempRow);
                        ViewState["TempTable"] = tempTable;

                        // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
                        grdList.DataSource = tempTable;
                        grdList.DataBind();
                    }
                }

                //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
                SetPreviousData();
     }
```

**SetInitialRowToGrid() code is given below:**

```
private void SetInitialRowToGrid()
    {
        // Initialize and Set initial row of Datatable
        var tempDataTable = new DataTable();
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("Emp_ID");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("First_Name");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("Created_Time");
        tempDataTable.Columns.Add("Plan_ID");
        tempDataTable.Rows.Add("1", "", "", "");

        // Store that datatable into viewstate
        ViewState["TempTable"] = tempDataTable;

        // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable
        grdList.DataSource = tempDataTable;
        grdList.DataBind();
    }
```

**SetPreviousData() code is given below:**

```
private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["TempTable"] != null)
        {
            var tempTable = (DataTable)ViewState["TempTable"];

            if (tempTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < tempTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var EmpID =
                        (Label)grdEmp.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblEmpID");
                    var firstName =
                        (Label)grdEmp.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblFirstName");

                    var date = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                    var planID =
                        (Label)grdList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("lblPlanID");

                    EmpID.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["Emp_ID"].ToString();
                    firstName.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["First_Name"].ToString();
                    date = tempTable.Rows[i]["Created_Time"].ToString();
                    planID.Text = tempTable.Rows[i]["Plan_ID"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen your `tempTable` rows in debugging mode?

Comment: @vallabha yeah data is there... I can see that.

Comment: `grdList` is the 3rd grid that you want to append rows one by one right?

Comment: @vallabha yes you are correct...

Comment: try clearing the datasource before assigning datasource as `grdList.DataSource.Clear()` or `dataGridView1.DataSource = null;`

Comment: where I suppose to do that? Is it in the SetInitialRowToGrid() or in the click event?

Comment: before this line `grdList.DataSource = tempTable;`

Comment: @vallabha that not working...